# overriding behavior when 'submit' button clicked in Django

Tags: django, button, methods, triggers

I am trying to develop a tennis ladder Django website that has classes for `Player`, `Match`, and `Ladder`. I have imported some dummy data and also have Create, Delete, Update, and List views for players and matches. But when a player is created, I need to also create a new Ladder object that will contain the new state of the ladder. Likewise, when a player is deleted (or is unavailable due to injury), the ladder state must change, and a new ladder is created. (I want to retain a historical record of each ladder state in case something is done by mistake ... this lets me revert to an earlier verson of the ladder). Finally, ladder positions change if a challenger defeats his or her opponent.

Here's my question. How do I trigger such code in a DeleteView (e.g. deleting a player). For a CreateView, I use this approach:

```
class PlayerCreateView(CreateView):
    model =Player
    num_players = Player.objects.count()
    context_object_name = 'player'
    fields = ['ranking', 'first', 'last', 'cell', 'email', 'availability']
    template_name = 'player_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('players')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        num_players = Player.objects.all().count()
        ladders = Ladder.objects.all()
        # <CALL CODE TO CREATE NEW LADDER OBJECT>
        return response
```

But what about other scenarios like DeleteView? It seems you can still use form_valid, but logically that seems weird since there is nothing to validate. Is there a standard or 'best practice' approach for getting from typical CRUD buttons in the templates to calling the underlying logic you want to implement through methods or the like?